# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance() in

Tags: php, forms, swiftmailer

I need help...please!

My code is

```
<?php

require_once '../lib/swift_required.php';  

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.ramosefilho.com', 25)
  ->setUsername('marcacao@user.com')
  ->setPassword('user@++++')
;

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Contacto')    
 ->setFrom(array('marcacao@user.com' => 'webmaster'))
 ->setTo(array('marcacao@user.com'))    
 ->setBody('$body = "nome: ".$nome."\n";    

$body .= "morada: ".$morada."\n";    
$body .= "email: ".$email."\n";    
$body .= "telefone: ".$telefone."\n";    
$body .= "marca: ".marca."\n";    
$body .= "modelo: ".$modelo."\n";
$body .= "ano: ".$ano."\n";    
$body .= "informacao: ".$informacao."\n";')    
 ;

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

it look ok, but generate de error:

> " Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance() in
>   /home/ramosefi/public_html/smtp.php on line 6 "

Answer (score 1):

This error generated in 6 version. [Change](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html):

```
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('mail.ramosefilho.com', 25))
  ->setUsername('marcacao@user.com')
  ->setPassword('user@++++')
;

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new Swift_Message('Contacto'))    
 ->setFrom(array('marcacao@user.com' => 'webmaster'))
 ->setTo(array('marcacao@user.com'))    
 ->setBody('$body = "nome: ".$nome."\n";    

$body .= "morada: ".$morada."\n";    
$body .= "email: ".$email."\n";    
$body .= "telefone: ".$telefone."\n";    
$body .= "marca: ".marca."\n";    
$body .= "modelo: ".$modelo."\n";
$body .= "ano: ".$ano."\n";    
$body .= "informacao: ".$informacao."\n";')    
 ;

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```